# Area chart in base R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to create an area chart like the following in base R? That is, without ggplot2, plotly, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  just fill in under the curve using `polygon`.  Here is a simple example.

```
x = seq(0,5.5*pi, 0.03)
y = 1 + sin(x)

plot(x,y, type="l")
Px = c(x, x[length(x)], 0)
Py = c(y, 0, 0)
polygon(Px, Py, col="lightblue")
```

[image: Area under curve]